# Mysql - How to log access from not granted hosts

Tags: mysql, logging

I have the following scenario:

```
MySQL server:
IP: 192.168.0.1
user: testing
pass: testing123123

MySQL client #1:
IP: 192.168.0.2

MySQL client #2:
IP: 192.168.0.3
```

Into MySQL server:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO testing@'192.168.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'testing123123';
flush privileges;
```

Client #1 is granted and Client #2 is NOT granted.

Then in Client #1 shell:

```
mysql -h192.168.0.1 -uuser_bla_bla -pbla_bla_bla
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user_bla_bla'@'192.168.0.2' (using password: YES)
```

Into Mysql Server log:

```
2017-03-11 12:13:10 82588 [Warning] Access denied for user 'user_bla_bla'@'192.168.0.2' (using password: YES)
```

Everything is OK: wrong username/password >> access denied >> log recorded

Now Client #2 shell:

```
mysql -h192.168.0.1 -uuser_bla_bla -pbla_bla_bla
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Into Mysql Server log: **NOTHING!**

My my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
log_warnings = 2
log_error=/var/log/mysql_error.log
```

MySQL log is not logging "host is not allowed", it only logs "Access denied for user".

*QUESTION: How to log MySQL "host is not allowed" cases?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced up with neccesity to find out the source of unwanted login attempts to my MySQL 5.7 server and found this question. So, here is solution that works:

1. enable general-log in `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-query.log
general_log = 1
```

2. restart mysql
3. wait for a while and look at the collected data:

```
grep -B 1 'Access denied' /var/log/mysql/mysql-query.log
```

You will see something like

```
2022-05-13T19:33:27.278884Z         2 Connect   root@localhost on  using Socket
2022-05-13T19:33:27.278923Z         2 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
--
2022-05-13T19:34:02.517332Z        10 Connect   bad_user@bad-ip-addr on my_database using TCP/IP
2022-05-13T19:34:02.517392Z        10 Init DB   Access denied for user 'bad_user'@'%' to database 'my_database'
--
```

Column with numbers (i.e. 2, 10 ) after the timestamp contains the Connection ID and you can easily match unwanted users with their addresses.

Be aware of leaving `general_log` enabled could lead to high consumption of disk space and possibility of performance degradation